# Char array to numeric array in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have the following matrix `A` of size 3x2:

```
A = [12; 34; 56];
```

But the data is stored as **chars**. I want to convert it to the numeric array. str2num doesn't. Is there another method to do that?

Comment: arrayfun and str2num?, Anyway this question is quite badly written. Why can't you show the data as you have it and what you expect and where str2num fails?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you have

```
A = ['12'; '34'; '56']; %// strings
```

and want to get

```
B = [1 2; 3 4; 5 6]; %// numbers
```

This could be done as follows: convert `A` to `double` to produce each character's ASCII code, and then subtract the code of character `'0'` to obtain the desired numbers. In fact, conversion to `double` is done implicitly when you subtract `char`s, so you can just use

```
B = A-'0';
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, your array doesn't look like a 3-by-2 array. In any case, you are looking for a casting function:

```
A = double(A);
```

should convert your `chars` in `double`.

Comment: Thanks. But it creates a matrix of ASCII codes of the chars.

Comment: ok, ca you post your reall array ? This is not a 3-by-2 array. Please also post the code that generated the array.

Comment: It is based loading a tab seperated data file using tdfread, unfortunatelly I can't load the data set.

Comment: ok, can you post the output of `disp(A)` and `class(A)` please ?